# Delete JSON item inside an sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wonder how can I unset the target array whenever i wanted in PHP. It's a product list and the procedure im planning if i want to delete a products. Here's the JSON structure

```
{
"Merchant": "SAMHONEY",
"date": 1632482493,
"archive": "true",
"extra": "Byahe",
"data": [
    {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mobi.asia\/assets\/abunjing-stand.png",
        "name": "Sample Product",
        "des": "Byahe Palawan Merchant Dashboard v.1.1",
        "price": "26"
    },
    {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mob.asia\/assets\/abunjing-stand.png",
        "name": "Sample Product 2",
        "des": "Byahe Palawan Merchant Dashboard v.1.1",
        "price": "99"
    },
    {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mob.asia\/01162020\/images\/storage\/1632200295.png",
        "name": "Product C",
        "des": "Great coffee",
        "price": "3"
    },
    {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mob.asia\/01162020\/images\/storage\/1632200342.png",
        "name": "Product A",
        "des": "Caramel Coffee",
        "price": "4"
    }
]
}
```

What I done in PHP is this

```
$pos = $_POST['position'];
$jsn = file_get_contents('../datamer/archives/'.$sbd.".json");
$arr = json_decode($jsn, true);
$acc = $arr["data"];   

unset($acc[$pos]);  

$arr["data"] =$acc;
file_put_contents('../datamer/archives/'.$sbd.".json",json_encode($arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

And the output is it was re-structuring the JSON into this.Which not im expecting

```
{
"Merchant": "SAMHONEY",
"date": 1632482493,
"archive": "true",
"extra": "Byahe",
"data": {
    "0": {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mobile.byahe.asia\/assets\/abunjing-stand.png",
        "name": "Sample Product",
        "des": "Byahe Palawan Merchant Dashboard v.1.1",
        "price": "26"
    },
    "2": {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mobile.byahe.asia\/01162020\/images\/storage\/1632200295.png",
        "name": "Product C",
        "des": "Great coffee",
        "price": "3"
    },
    "3": {
        "product-image": "https:\/\/mobile.byahe.asia\/01162020\/images\/storage\/1632200342.png",
        "name": "Product A",
        "des": "Caramel Coffee",
        "price": "4"
    }
}
  }
```

Kindly enlighten me to this. I'm still learning,. Thanks in advance for the attention. Well appreciated.

Comment: Only arrays that are numerically indexed, starting at 0 and with no "gaps", can be expressed as arrays in JSON. Anything else _needs_ to get converted to an object, so that the arbitrary keys can become property names then. If you don't need to keep the original (implicit) indexes, then just do `$arr["data"] = array_values($arr["data"]);` after you unset the element, that will re-index your array.

Comment: Or, in one go: `array_splice( $arr['data'], $pos, 1 );`

Comment: Okay I'll give a try. Thanks a lot

Comment: It did worked. Thanks for the solution ```array_splice( $arr['data'], $pos, 1 );``` this code, i just replace the ```unset```